# PDF iTextSharp, write PDF line to different page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I'm working on a previous employee's buggy code
(How I love working on other people's code), ad he's creating a pdf using iTextSharp ASP framework 4.0, c#

He's using:

```
if (yindex <= 100)
{
Cb.PdfDocument.NewPage();

Cb.SetCMYKColorStroke(100, 60, 0, 18);
yindex = 770;
}
Cb.BeginText();
Cb.SetFontAndSize(Font, FontSize);
Cb.ShowTextAligned(Alignment, text, xPos, yindex, rotation);
Cb.EndText();
```

Basically what is happening is hes printing a list of times, keeping a running total of their amounts, once the section is completed, he trying to set the yindex back to the top of the page and write a header whit a total.

This works fine if there is one page, however when a section spans multiple pages, setting the yindex to the top of the page sets the text to the top of the current page. How would I keep track of what page the header should be on, and then set the yindex to correct height on the correct page?

Comment: As soon as you do `NewPage`, the former page is written to file. Thus, you cannot simply go back to that page to add content to it. What you could do instead, though, is create an empty `PdfTemplate` when you start a section, and include it at the top of the current page. When finishing the section, draw the header text line in that template and the store it. Alternatively you can store page number and header line in some collection; when the pdf without headers is finished, simply open it in a `PdfStamper` and add the headers to the indicated pages.

Comment: Whoever wrote `Cb.PdfDocument.NewPage();` should get an itch in a place he can't reach. That is indeed some very buggy code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would throw away the code that writes the header along with the rest of the data, and introduce a page event that adds the header in the `OnEndPage()` event.

To deal with the fact that you only know the total when page X is reached whereas you may need that total on pages X - 1, X -2,... I would use a `PdfTemplate` (as mkl suggests).

This is demonstrated in examples such as [`MovieCountries1`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104) (see http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C04 for the C# counterpart).

Using a page event has the benefit that you don't need to keep track of the pages, you can keep the code that draws the header separate from the rest of the business logic. See http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/events/ for some more examples.